# Microsoft Access Datediff issue

Tags: ms-access

I feel like this shouldn't be hard at this point.. but for some reason I cannot figure it out.  Using Microsoft Access to calculate someone's age at a certain date with this.

```
=DateDiff("yyyy",[Dob],(2/1/2014))+Int(Format((2/1/2014),"mmdd")<Format([Dob],"mmdd"))
```

Where Dob = 5/14/2003 .  It is returning -104.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
=DateDiff("yyyy",[Dob],#2/1/2014#)+Int(Format(#2/1/2014#,"mmdd")<Format([Dob],"mmdd"))
```

Comment: Did I really just forget #... man its been a while since I've done much with Access.. haha .thanks.

Comment: We've all been there ;) If this worked for you, make sure to accept it as the answer.

Comment: I meant to do that yesterday but I was just being lazy after work and remembered that I didn't on the way home. I have done it now. Thanks. It is nice to see some people don't get all high and mighty over simple issues.

Comment: Beware! `DateDiff("yyyy", #2010-12-31#, #2011-01-01#)` will return 1 even though the difference is just one day!

Answer (score 0):

```
DATEDIFF("d",[Dob],(2/1/2014))/365
```

Get the days and divide by 365 instead...